# How to control oculus rotation and potition in unity 5.3.x

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I want to control the rotation and position of the Oculus DK2 in Unity 5.3 over. It doesn't seems to be trivial, I've already tried all I could find on unity forum, but nothing seems to works. The CameraRig script doesn't look to do anything when i change it. I want to disable all rotation and position because I have a mocap system that more reliable for those things.

Need some help!

Answer (score 2):

To be able to control the pose your camera must be represented by using a OVRCameraRig that is included with the [OVRPlugin for Unity 5](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/game-engines/1.3.2/OVRPlugin_for_Unity_5/).

Once you have that you can use the `UpdatedAnchors` event from the camera to transform the mocap data on to the camera position, just overwrite the value of `OVRCameraRig.trackerAnchor` for the head and `OVRCameraRig.leftHandAnchor` and `OVRCameraRig.rightEyeAnchor`for hand positions if your suit supports those.

```
public class MocapController : MonoBehavior
{    
    public OVRCameraRig camera; //Drag camera rig object on to the script in the editor.

    void Awake()
    {
        camera.UpdatedAnchors += UpdateAnchors 
    }

    void UpdatedAnchors(OVRCameraRig rigToUpdate)
    {
        Transform headTransform = GetHeadTransform(); //Write yourself
        Transform lHandTransform = GetLHandTransform(); //Write yourself
        Transform rHandTransform = GetRHandTransform(); //Write yourself

        rigToUpdate.trackerAnchor = headTransform;
        rigToUpdate.leftHandAnchor= lHandTransform;
        rigToUpdate.rightHandAnchor= rHandTransform;
    }
}
```